# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'set'

Tags: python

```py
import math


def cal(v1, v2, dt, m, rho, A, D):
    k = -D * rho * A * dt / 2 / m

    ve = {-k*(v1+v2) + math.sqrt(math.pow((k*(v1+v2)),2)-4*k*{k*v1*v2+v1-v2})}/(2*k)
    return ve

m = 16.2*10**-3
rho = 1.225

A = 2*10**-4
D = 0.47


v1 = 0.350313
v2 = 0.301598
dt = 1.329709


ve = cal(v1, v2, dt, m, rho, A, D)

print(ve)
```

From executing this code, I got error:

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'set'`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line

```py
ve = {-k*(v1+v2) + math.sqrt(math.pow((k*(v1+v2)),2)-4*k*{k*v1*v2+v1-v2})}/(2*k)
```

to

```py
ve = (-k*(v1+v2) + math.sqrt(math.pow((k*(v1+v2)),2)-4*k*(k*v1*v2+v1-v2)))/(2*k)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
-3.536702464867566
```

In python values enclosed inside `{ }` are either set or dictionary, and inside `[  ]` are lists. You should always use small parenthesis `(  )` to serve the purpose of brackets

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating a set by using the `{` `}` braces within the `ve` operation.

And because you are trying to use multiplication, and the multiplication operation is between a float (left hand side `k`) and the set, it fails as it is unsupported.

Remove the `{}` inside your equation and you should be fine.